# Associating values from one list with values in another programmatically

Tags: python, list

(Asking again in a more concise way)

I have four lists of values and I need to link the first and last together like this:

[image]

so that I can plot the points (4, 8350.1416), (10, 13167.329), (15, 29200.063), etc.

The `enumerate` function can give me access to the indices of the rightmost list, but how can I associate the values in that one with the correct values in the leftmost list?

The lists change with each run of the code, so I need to do it programmatically, like in a `for` loop for example.

EDIT: My program reads the pixel values along a randomly selected row. List1 holds the minimum-valued pixels, and list2 holds their values. Then list3 holds the minimum values of those minimum values, and list4 holds their values. Describing it like that sounds a lot more confusing than it is!

I've tried using

```
ubermin_vals_x = []
for i in ubermin_values:
    value = ubermin_pixels[i]
    ubermin_vals_x.append(minimum_pixels[i])
```

but it tries to iterate over the values (8350.1416, 13167.329...) which of course can't be done.

I'm trying to plot the lists to look like this:

[image]

but have the black carets from list4 at the correct points along the x-axis, which are given in list1.

Comment: Is list 2 really necessary?  It looks like you just go from list 4->3->1

Comment: I'm plotting the lists on a graph, and the last thing I need to plot is those points in the first and last lists.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of the four lists - that we can copy and use. [mcve]

Comment: why don't u share your raw data

Comment: Have you made an attempt to solve the problem?

Comment: The lists are several hundred elements long, and they change with every run of the program. I'll put some minimal examples here.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain more about what you are doing at a conceptual level

Comment: You should be able to "invert" lists 1 and 3 with a dict comprehension like: `d = {k:v[0] for (k,v) in enumerate(lst)}` -- that and [`list.index(element)`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) should help you backtrack however you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, everyone, especially @Vincenzoo

It works now with this:

```
uberminxlist = []
uberminylist = []
for i in ubermin_pixels:
    uberminxlist.append(minimum_pixels[i[0]])
    uberminylist.append(minimum_values[i[0]])
```

Lovely :)

Answer (score 2):

Naming lists from left to right as l1,l2,l3,l4 l2 seems useless to me, since it just replicates the value in l4, so if I understand the problem, the code could be:

```
for i,v in zip(l3,l4):
    print (l1[i],v)  #or  plot
```

and you can replace `v` with `l2[i]`.
Or even simpler:

```
for i in l3:
    print (l1[i],l2[i])
```

As from comment below in your example elements of l3 seem to be sigle-element list, the code becomes:

```
for i in l3:
    print (l1[i[0]],l2[i[0]])
```

Comment: with your solutions I get
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Comment: it's because the elements of your list are lists of one element. It's not clear to me why, but if this is always the case, you can replacei with i[0] and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear to me what you are trying to do, but here is my guess

1. find the index of element in 4th array in 2nd array
2. use that index to extract the number in 1st array

and the implementation is as follows

```
a4 = [ 8350.1416, 13167.329, 29200.063 ] 
a2 = [13846, 8350.1416, 0, 13167.329, 0, 29200.063]
a1 = [1, 4, 7, 10, 12, 15, 18]
idx = [a1[a2.index(x)] for x in a4]
result = zip(idx, a4)
```

I also suspect @Vincenzooo 's answer is already very close to what you want. Maybe

```
for i in l3:
    print (l1[i[0]],l2[i[0]])
```

Comment: then you have to replace also the second index with i[0]